# What is the benefit to define a function in a function in python?

Tags: python, function, syntax

I encountered this piece of python code (pasted below) on [effbot](https://web.archive.org/web/20200704001242/http://effbot.org/zone/re-sub.htm#unescape-html) and I was wondering:

**Why defining a function within a function?**

```
import re, htmlentitydefs

##
# Removes HTML or XML character references and entities from a text string.
#
# @param text The HTML (or XML) source text.
# @return The plain text, as a Unicode string, if necessary.

def unescape(text):
    def fixup(m):
        text = m.group(0)
        if text[:2] == "&#":
            # character reference
            try:
                if text[:3] == "&#x":
                    return unichr(int(text[3:-1], 16))
                else:
                    return unichr(int(text[2:-1]))
            except ValueError:
                pass
        else:
            # named entity
            try:
                text = unichr(htmlentitydefs.name2codepoint[text[1:-1]])
            except KeyError:
                pass
        return text # leave as is
    return re.sub("(?s)<[^>]*>|&#?\w+;", fixup, text)
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

> Why defining a function within a function?

To keep it isolated.  It's only used in this one place.  Why define it more globally when it's used locally?

Comment: It is pretty common to define inner functions for using closures but It seems the current case is the one you mentioned (and it is a good reason as well). Ergo, +1

Answer (score 8):

It's just another way of breaking down a large function into smaller pieces without polluting the global namespace with another function name.  Quite often the inner function isn't a stand-alone so doesn't rightfully belong in the global namespace.

Answer (score 7):

Often the main reason of such code is function [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29). It is powerful thing that is applicable not only to Python.  E.g. JavaScript gains a lot from them.

Some points about closures in Python - [closures-in-python](http://ynniv.com/blog/2007/08/closures-in-python.html).