# Function not defined after declaration in python3

Tags: python, montecarlo

Using python 3: I have three functions: montePi, isInCircle and main.
I need to have the isInCircle called by montePi. The function will work, it just says that isInCircle is not defined. How can I define it?

```
import random
import math

def montePi(numDarts):

    inCircle = 0

    def isInCircle(x, y, r):
        r = 1
        d = math.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
        if d <= r:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    for i in range(numDarts):
        x = random.random()
        y = random.random()
        d = math.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
        if d <= 1:
            inCircle = inCircle +1
        pi = inCircle / numDarts * 4
    return pi

def main():
    print(montePi(100))
    print(montePi(1000))
    print(montePi(10000))
    print(montePi(100000))
main()
```

Comment: Why is `isInCircle()` defined in the middle of `montePi()`?

Comment: Why not just define `isInCircle` outside of `montePi` and then call it?

Comment: I guess I'm having trouble where to define it outside of montePi and how to call it. I think I'm confused on how to connect the two

Comment: Where are you calling `isInCircle()`?

Comment: For a hard-coded radius of 1, the call to `math.sqrt` is unnecessary.

Comment: @EmmaSteele There's no difference in how you connect them. `if isInCircle(x, y, 1):`

Comment: `pi = inCircle / numDarts * 4` doesn't need to be in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Because function `isInCircle` is defined in `montePi`, it can be called within `montePi` but not other functions as it is local. If you define `isInCircle` outside of `montePi` then you'll be able to call it from `main`.

Not sure what you're trying to program here, but there seems to be a chance that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791198/what-is-the-benefit-to-define-a-function-in-a-function-in-python), regarding functions within functions can help you decide what you want here. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules) is a question that covers how scopes work.

Should you need to call `isInCircle` from `main` or outside `main`, then this is how it should be formatted;

```
import random
import math

def isInCircle(x, y, r):
    r = 1
    d = math.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
    if d <= r:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def montePi(numDarts):

    inCircle = 0

    for i in range(numDarts):
        x = random.random()
        y = random.random()
        d = math.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
        if d <= 1:
            inCircle = inCircle +1
        pi = inCircle / numDarts * 4
    return pi

def main():
    print(montePi(100))
    print(montePi(1000))
    print(montePi(10000))
    print(montePi(100000))
main()
```